# Is a way to use System.IO.Compression.ZipFile in C# to add folder without createFromDirectory?

Tags: c#, .net, file, zip

I need to zip a folder that contains folders, common files and zipfiles. But I need to except the files with the "zip" extension. Also I need to create the zipfile or update it if is already created.

In order to do this, I check all files and directories and then add the files to the zip file. So far so good, but I can't find a way to add or update a folder.

This is my last tried:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(directoryToCompress).Where(name => !name.EndsWith(".zip", true, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(directoryToCompress);

if (File.Exists(filenameZip))
{
    using (ZipArchive zipDest = ZipFile.Open(filenameZip,ZipArchiveMode.Update))
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            zipDest.
            zipDest.CreateEntryFromFile(file, Path.GetFileName(file), CompressionLevel.Optimal);
            System.IO.File.Delete(file);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    using (ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.Open(filenameZip, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            zip.CreateEntryFromFile(file, Path.GetFileName(file), CompressionLevel.Optimal);
            System.IO.File.Delete(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any tip or help